# removing duplicates based on one column but not duplicate in another column but want to remove the whole line

Tags: linux, files, text

I have a text file with so many lines with two columns, but i want to remove the whole line based on duplicate of a column but not duplicated in another column. I have following example of my data

```
ASV000001       76.697
ASV000002       75.667
ASV000003       81.044
ASV000003       85.976
ASV000004       81.218
ASV000004       81.596
ASV000005       79.612
ASV000006       81.726
ASV000006       81.983
ASV000007       99.385
```

For example, from the above data, i want to remove the second linein following duplicate

```
ASV000003       81.044
ASV000003       85.976
```

Please give the possibility to do it in linux platform. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `ASV000004` it seems to have duplicate also?

Comment: Wait, you want to remove both (all) instances of `ASV000003` because it isn't unique? Or did you mean to say to wanted to remove the second (and subsequent) instance so there was only one left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), using one of the most idiomatic trick of `awk`:

```
$ awk '!seen[$1]++' file
ASV000001       76.697
ASV000002       75.667
ASV000003       81.044
ASV000004       81.218
ASV000005       79.612
ASV000006       81.726
ASV000007       99.385
```

Comment: Great, thanks. exactly what i wanted do!